# NHibernate mapping differences between 2.0 and 2.2

Tags: nhibernate

What are the differences in syntax and semantics between NHibernate mapping 2.0 and 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look a look at the release-notes:

http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/releasenotes.txt?view=markup

But as far as I remember there are no mapping changes.